# Как нажать на кнопку, которая находится в shadow-root через javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как при помощи js кликнуть по кнопке "Детали" ?

Эта страница - chrome://extensions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У элемента есть свойство [`shadowRoot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot), к которому можно применить уже методы для выбора элементов такие как `.querySelector` и другие.

---

Также хром предоставляет возможность скопировать селектор к элементу, в том числе и для `js`.

Для этого можно нажать правой кнопкой на нужном элементе и выбрать `Copy` ->  `Copy js path`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что в результате может дать следующее

```
document.querySelector("body > extensions-manager").shadowRoot.querySelector("#items-list").shadowRoot.querySelector("#dpngiggdglpdnjdoaefidgiigpemgage").shadowRoot.querySelector("#detailsButton")
```

Comment: О господи, вы мой спаситель. Я 5 часов пытался найти как можно активировать расширение в режиме инкогнито и не хватало только этого звена. browser.execute_script("return document.querySelector('extensions-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#viewManager > extensions-detail-view.active').shadowRoot.querySelector('div#container.page-container > div.page-content > div#options-section extensions-toggle-row#allow-incognito').shadowRoot.querySelector('label#label input').click()")   Вот активатор, если кому-нибуль понадобится.